# Simulink: How does one assign a double to a constant in a subsystem through the mask?

Tags: matlab, simulink

This is a slightly long-winded problem, but should be easy to follow along.

**End goal**: Input a 'double' vector into a C++ S Function by assigning it to a Constant.

**Starting point**: A function within the Dialog Callback of my masked subsystem returns the double vector that I need.

**Steps in the middle**: So I have a double vector as an input, I need a double vector as an output, but I cannot pass the vector directly, because `set_param` requires that I pass the value as a string.

**Problem**: What I tried is this: `set_param(gcb,'refNameArray',num2str(refName));`

where,

- gcb (correctly) returns the block from within which I am doing
  everything.
- refNameArray is the parameter which needs to be assigned
  the double vector
- refName is the vector, in 'double' form, that I
  have available within the dialog callback of the mask.

I use num2str because I cannot directly assign a vector, I must input it as a string.
But, even using num2str, I get an error saying `Invalid Setting in Block <blockName> for parameter 'Value'`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you set for param in the dialog should be syntactically similar to an RHS expression in MATLAB. For example, for a vector value you would need to set it as '[1 3 4]'. Notice the square brackets. num2str does not add that square brackets. You can either add it manually at the ends before calling set_param or you can use mat2str which will create the string with the brackets.

Comment: Fantastic! I thought the Simulink user-community was dead and buried. Thank you for banishing that thought from my head!